# Using self as a Generic Type Constraint

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine, singleton

I am fairly new to Generic Types, but still tried my hand at writting a generic Singleton behaviour for Unity, starting with this declaration :

```
public abstract class Singleton<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : Singleton<T>{}
```

then promptly tested it by declaring two child classes :

```
public class Example : Singleton<Example> {}
public class Fraud   : Singleton<Example> {}
```

I expected an error, but this actually compiled.
To my understanding, `where T : Singleton<T>` should have been enough to force `Fraud` to derive from `Singleton<Fraud>`, but apparently it doesn't.

What did I get wrong ?
Is there actually a way to enforce such a constraint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Example : Singleton<Example> {}
```

The constraint on `Singleton<T>` is `T : Singleton<T>`. Substitute `T := Example`, and you get the constraint `Example : Singleton<Example>`, which holds because that's how we declared `Example`. No issues.

---

```
public class Fraud  : Singleton<Example> {}
```

The constraint on `Singleton<T>` is `T : Singleton<T>`. Substitute `T := Example`, and you get the constraint `Example : Singleton<Example>`, which holds because that's how we declared `Example`. No issues.

---

There's no reason for `Fraud` to *not* be valid, so it *is* valid. After all, the point of F-bounded polymorphism is method chaining, and you can chain methods on `Fraud` just as well as you can on `Example`. It might not do the same thing, but that's the same kind of problem you'd get if you created a new `IDictionary` that ignored every second call to `Add`: you can't use the type system to enforce everything (unless you're Coq); you can't always stop external entities from doing things they shouldn't do.

Comment: I realize how badly I misinterpreted this constraint.  
I take it there is no constraint that can achieve the result I was looking for ?